# Starting, Stopping A Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am not really sure how thread works.

Here is my code. Upon clicking a send button:

```
protected void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread threadA = new Thread(SendSMS);
    threadA.Start();
}

protected void SendSMS()
{
    //some validations here
    Thread threadB = new Thread(loadingScreen);
    threadB.Start();
    threadB.Join();
    //code that actually sends the required Mail
    threadB.Stop();
    loading.Visible = false;
}
```

threadB is calling this method which is basically a div (called loading) with a loading div that disables user from pressing anything on screen:

```
protected void loadingScreen()
{
    loading.Visible = true;
}
```

Now the mail is being sent but the loading screen (div) is not becoming visible.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are we talking about ASP.NET?

Comment: Just put `Join` after sending mail - before stop (Join makes nothing but waits till thread completes). Also make sure your `loadingScreen` method infinitely blocks screen when called alone.

Answer (score 4):

You have to rethink when you're writing ASP.NET vs. a rich client application. In short (really really short) the web browser (client) sends a request to the server. The server handles that request (that part is your code behind), and returns a result to the web browser.

When you show a DIV in your codebehind, do some work, then hide it again, only the result will arrive at the web browser.

There are multiple ways to achieve the optical effect you want, but you must know about the Life Cycle of ASP.NET first. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a responseable application while you compute a huge task.
In WinForms you have to be careful because if you want to change some UI like a Text in a Label you have to synchronize both Threads. (UI-Thread and Thread1)
If you are running .NET 4.0 you should use the Task-Class, because there you don't need to synchronize and you can also use anonymous methods.

```
protected void SendSMS()
{
    loading.Visible = true;

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{//code that actually sends the required Mail}

    task.Wait();
    loading.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the loading Gets visible and then hidden quickly. Join returns immediately as soon as it enabled the Div and then the email is sent, the Div is disabled again. Sending email and disabling happens in same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use threadB? You can do operation only with threadA:

```
protected void SendSMS()
```

{

//some validations here

```
loading.Visible = false;

//code that actually sends the required Mail

loading.Visible = false;
```

}

Warning for crossthread operation exception.